# Returning correct value from factory

Tags: javascript, factory

Trying to create a factory in JavaScript, when I pass in a value to the factory I want it to return the correct string instead of the integer.

```
function Factory(amount){
  switch (amount) {
    case amount == 1:
      return "one "
      break;
    case amount == 2:
      return "two "
      break;
    case amount > 2:
      return "more than two "
      break;
  }
  return amount;
}

var per1 = Factory(1);
console.log(per1, 'per1');
var per2 = Factory(2);
var per3 = Factory(3);
```

But when I log out `per1` I get the value: `1` instead of `'one '`.

What have I not done quite right?

Comment: Here's how w3schools teaches it -> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch case works on values, instead of `true/false`

```
function Factory(amount){
  switch (amount) {
    case 0:
      return "zero "
    case 1:
      return "one "
    case 2:
      return "two "
    default:
      return "more than two "
  }
}
```

You also don't need to `break` since you already have `return`.

The `default` case handles the rest of the cases if not mentioned above. So you also don't need to `return amount` as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

```
      function Factory(amount){
          switch (amount) {
            case 1:
              return "one "

            case 2:
              return "two "

            default:
              return "more than two "

        }
    }
```

change you case like this

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
function Factory(amount){
  switch (amount) {
    case 1:
      return "one "
      break;
    case 2:
      return "two "
      break;

  }
  return amount;
}



console.log(Factory(1))
//output "one"
```

Comment: You don't need to break after return I believe